# How to print list items as if they're contents of print in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

words_list = ['who', 'got', '\n', 'inside', 'your', '\n', 'mind', 'baby']

I have this list of words stored as a list element. I wanted to use the elements as contents of the print function. Ex.

```
print(words_list[0] + words_list[1] + words_list[2]...words_list[n])
```

My desired output would be:

> ```
> who got 
> inside your
> mind baby
> ```

Comment: `print( ''.join(words_list) )` will concat the list items using '' as "seperator" into one string

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks! that worked! how can i close this question and choose your answer as the best one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 you can do:

```
print(*words_list)
```

because print is just a function and the `*` operator in this context will [unpack elements of your list and put them as positional arguments of the function call](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

In older versions you'd need to concatenate (join) elements of the array first, possibly converting them to strings, if they are not strings already. This can be done like this:

```
print ' '.join([str(w) for w in words_list])
```

or, more succinctly, using generator expression instead of list comprehension:

```
print ' '.join(str(w) for w in words_list)
```

Yet another alternative is to use the `map` function, which results in even shorter code:

```
print ' '.join(map(str, words_list))
```

However, if you are on Python 2.6+ but not on Python 3, you can get print as a function by importing it from the future:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(*words_list)
```

Comment: That's not exactly correct. You can use `print` as a function in Python 2.7 (maybe older versions, too, but these should not be used since years). Just import the correct future, which is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Why use a list comprehension? print(' '.join(word_list)) would produce the same output.